# Json files in android

Tags: android, json, hashmap

I have a set of offline data in JSON file which i kept in res->raw folder and parsed. I started parsing it using JSONArray and JSONObject and mapped 3 interlinked files using HashMap and Vector. But now when i find multiple events(arrays) it goes with many HashMap and Vectors, then went on a big time google search and found using JSONSerializer, JSON Tokener and JSON Stringer we can make it simple. Which is better to use? Hashmap and Vector or JSON Tokener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends but better and easy option is to use create a `POJO` class and use the `List<POJOClass> list = new ArrayList<POJOClass>();` and store the data. Don't use Vector as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had pretty good luck serializing/derserializing nested JSON objects with arrays using Google's [**GSON**](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.